# Doctrine tool breaking Symfony Dialog Helper in ZF2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I recently updated ZF2 and started getting this error in the command line when using the Doctrine tool. While it does not effect the work being done, it is annoying.

I have searched about but as I am relatively new to using Doctrine, I am not 100% sure what I need to do to fix this:

> PHP Deprecated:  "Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\DialogHelper" is
>   deprecated since version 2.5 and will be removed in 3.0. Use
>
> "Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper" instead. in
>   /var/www/cloud/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/DialogHelper.php on line
>   34 PHP Stack trace:

I am using ZF2 version: 2.4

Thanks for any help on this!

Answer (score 0):

running `composer update` cleared up the problem for me.